# Angular AG-Grid is not loaded/displayed correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I followed the official instructions and did all the steps from the official installing Guide from the AG-Grid Components. When I run my project the Grid isn't displaying correctly and it looks like the styling doesn't load correctly.

[AG-Grid incorrect Displaying Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y94o.png)

This includes downloading the correct version, specifying it in the app-module file in the imports and inserting the imports in Style.css. Nevertheless, the grid is displayed incorrectly and without styling. I have also tried different versions and uninstalled and reinstalled them.

**client-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ClientService } from "app/modules/billing/services/client.service";
import { Client } from "app/modules/billing/models/client";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { GridOptions, ColDef } from "ag-grid-community";
import { AuthGuard } from 'app/auth/auth.guard';

@Component({
  selector: "app-client-list",
  templateUrl: "./client-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./client-list.component.scss"],
})
export class ClientListComponent implements OnInit {
  clients$: Observable<Client[]> | any;
  page: number = 1;
  count: number = 0;
  tableSize: number = 9;
  searchText: string = "";
  coreId: number = 0;
  user: any;
  viewerClient: boolean = false;
  gridApi :any;
  gridColumnApi: any;

  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { headerName: "Business ID", field: "bpId" },
    { headerName: "CO-RE ID", field: "coreId" },
    { headerName: "Full Name", field: "fullName" }
  ];

  rowData: Client[] = [];

  constructor(public service: ClientService, private router: Router, public authGuard: AuthGuard, private keyClaokService: KeycloakService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.authGuard.hasAdminRole()){
      this.getAllClients();
    } else {
      this.getUserCoreId();
    }
  }

  getAllClients(): void {
    this.service.getAllClients().subscribe((data) => {
      this.rowData = data;
    });
  }

  onGridReady(params: GridOptions) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(Number(this.tableSize));
  }

  onSearch() {
    if (this.searchText == "") {
      this.getAllClients();
    } else {
      this.gridApi?.setQuickFilter(this.searchText);
    }
  }

  getUserCoreId():void{
    const keyCloakInstance = this.keyClaokService.getKeycloakInstance();
    const user = keyCloakInstance.idTokenParsed;
    this.coreId = user?.coreId;
    this.service.getOwnDetail();
  }
}
```

**client-list.component.html**

```
<div style="width: 100%;" *ngIf="authGuard.hasAdminRole(); else singleClient">
  <input class="search" type="text" name="searchText" [(ngModel)]="searchText"
         (ngModelChange)="onSearch()" placeholder="Enter name to search" style="margin-top:10px" />
  <ag-grid-angular
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
  </ag-grid-angular>

</div>
<ng-template #singleClient>
  <app-client></app-client>
</ng-template>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**style.css**

```
@import '~@six/ui-library/dist/ui-library/ui-library.css';
@import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
.bubble-alert {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CoreModule} from './core/core.module';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {KeycloakAngularModule} from "keycloak-angular";
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from "@angular/material/snack-bar";
import {AgGridModule} from "ag-grid-angular";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule, RouterModule, HttpClientModule, CoreModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, KeycloakAngularModule, AuthModule, MatSnackBarModule, AgGridModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Please share your package.json as well